# How many ways can 100 balls be placed in 5 urns?

Tags: combinatorics

...Such that the urn 1 needs at least 10 balls, urns 2 and 3 at least 12 each, urns 4 and 5 need at least 4 combined. The balls are identical.

Is the best way to go about this by subtracting the complement of these conditions being satisfied from the total possible conditions? What would be a systematic way to calculate these conditions?

Comment: @Henry, right...took me a minute to sort that out.

Comment: It needs to be specified as well whether or not the balls are distinct or indistinguishable.  Given the problem statement, it can be assumed that the urns are at least distinct since they have different requirements, but it cannot be automatically assumed for the balls given the limited information in the problem statement.

Comment: Edited! Sorry about that. The balls are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_k$ denote the number of balls placed in the $k$th urn.  We must find the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 100 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the constraints that $x_1 \geq 10$, $x_2 \geq 12$, $x_3 \geq 12$, $x_4 + x_5 \geq 4$.  Let 
\begin{align*}
x_1' & = x_1 - 10\\ 
x_2' & = x_2 - 12\\
x_3' & = x_3 - 12
\end{align*}
Then $x_1', x_2', x_3'$ are nonnegative integers.  Substituting $x_1' + 10$ for $x_1$, $x_2' + 12$ for $x_2$, and $x_3' + 12$ for $x_3$ in equation 1 yields 
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 10 + x_2' + 12 + x_3' + 12 + x_4 + x_5 & = 100\\
x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + x_4 + x_5 & = 66 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers.

The number of solutions of the equation 
$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + \ldots + y_k = n$$
in the nonnegative integers is given by the formula 
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$
since a given solution corresponds to the placement of $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones, and we must choose which $k - 1$ of the $n + k - 1$ positions needed for $n$ ones and $k - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

From the number of solutions of equation 2 in the nonnegative integers, we must exclude those in which $x_4 + x_5 < 4$.  There are four such cases.

1. $x_1' + x_2' + x_3' = 66$, $x_4 + x_5 = 0$
2. $x_1' + x_2' + x_3' = 65$, $x_4 + x_5 = 1$
3. $x_1' + x_2' + x_3' = 64$, $x_4 + x_5 = 2$
4. $x_1' + x_2' + x_3' = 63$, $x_4 + x_5 = 3$

To find the number of cases satisfying both the equations
\begin{align*}
x_4 + x_5 & = j\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 66 - j
\end{align*}
multiply the number of nonnegative integer solutions of $x_4 + x_5 = j$ by the number of nonnegative solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 66 - j$.